# IONIC working with JSON Format Advise

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am wondering which is actually the better method of handling this data in JSON. Especially working with IONIC

```
var quizs = [
        {id: 1, 
         question: '1.jpg', 
         desc: 'What color is displayed here', 
         answer: 'blue, green, orange'} 
]
```

or this

```
var quizs = [
        {id: 1, 
         question: '1.jpg', 
         desc: 'What color is displayed here', 
         answer: [{
              color: 'blue', 
              color: 'green', 
              color: 'orange'}] 
]
```

The second one seems to be too much in repeating.

Comment: Depends on your needs and business-logic.

Answer (score 1):

The second one isn't a valid object.
An object can't have multiple properties with the same name.

An option is to (properly) use an array, instead:

```
answer: ['blue', 'green', 'orange']
```

Using an array will have the advantage that you won't have to transform the `answer` to get one of the possible answers out of it.

To get `"blue"`, your first example would require:

```
quizs[0].answer.split(', ')[0]
```

Where the array wouldn't need the `split`:

```
quizs[0].answer[0]
```

Comment: *"The second one isn't valid syntax."*. It is perfectly valid syntax though.

Comment: [Yea, but...](http://www.ar15.com/media/mediaFiles/1715/18364.JPG) Nevermind. (Good point).

Comment: Cerbrus, dfsq : Thanks. This helps. Say..if I want to display the entries of my answers, do I do this ? 

`<div class="" data-ng-repeat="y in quiz.answer|orderBy:random track by $index">`    
`     {{y[$index]}}`
`</div>`

Comment: You don't need `$index`: `<div class="" data-ng-repeat="y in quiz.answer|orderBy:random"> {{y}} </div>`

Comment: I tried... doesn't work properly. Can you take a look at this ? https://jsfiddle.net/JSmithd/wtptadt8/1/